# I want to hide a button in flash when i click on it

Tags: flash, actionscript

Friends, I want to create a flash exercise. when i click on the object it should hide or disappear.

```
on (release) {
{
setProperty("button1",_visible,false);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`setProperty`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as2/reference/flashlite/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118cd9b5f6e-7a33.html) function is used like this :

```
setProperty(target:Object, property:Object, expression:Object) : Void
```

So here the `target` can be the object itself or its name, and because you are inside the timeline of the button, you can not use its name directly as you did in your code.

To get your object inside its timeline, you have many manners, so for your case you can do :

```
// In my case, the button1 object is inside the root timeline

on (release) {

    // you can use some traces to more understand

    trace(_parent);                     // gives : _level0
    trace(this._parent);                // gives : _level0      
    // this._parent is the same as _parent inside the timeline of our object        

    trace(this);                        // gives : _level0.button1

    // if you want to use the name of your object inside its timeline, you have to use it on reference with its parent 
    trace(this._parent[this._name]);    // gives : _level0.button1
    trace(this._parent['button1']);     // gives : _level0.button1
    trace(this._parent.button1);        // gives : _level0.button1

    // then you can pick a choice between all these notation : 

    var _this = this._parent['button1'];// this, this._parent[this._name] or this._parent.button1

    // to hide the object using setProperty
    setProperty(_this, _visible, false);

    // or simply without setProperty 
    _this._visible = false;

}
```

And if you are inside the timeline of the `parent` of your object, you can do :

```
button1.onRelease = function():Void {

    // to hide the object using setProperty, you can do
    setProperty(this, _visible, false);

    // or ( selected by its name )
    setProperty(this._name, _visible, false);

    // or ( selected by its name )
    setProperty('button1', _visible, false);

    // or
    setProperty(button1, _visible, false);

    // or simply without setProperty 
    this._visible = false;

    // or
    button1._visible = false;

    // or, using its name 
    this._parent[this._name]._visible = false;
    this._parent['button1']._visible = false;
    this._parent[button1]._visible = false;

}
```

I know that my answer could have been shorter, but I tried to clarify things to more understand it.

Hope that can help.